# How to compare formatted date strings

Tags: javascript, date

So I have dates in the following format 'dd.MM.yyyy' saved as strings and I would like to compare those.

I tried using the >= or <= operators and it doesn't work on strings. 
Yet it works fine on Date objects.

Therefore I would like to ask whether there is a way to compare formatted date strings or whether it's better to keep everything as date object.

Comment: Convert both date strings into date objects and compare.
String date1="31.12.1998";
Date dateObj=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(date1);

Comment: Where is `SimpleDateFormat` defined, @AmmarTahir?

Comment: If you have values that represent dates, and you want to compare them as dates, it is indeed best to keep them as dates.

Comment: @HereticMonkey. SimpleDateFormat is a public class. See for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @AmmarTahir The question is tagged JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Sorry. my bad..

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1) build date objects from these strings and compare them like you did before

2) reformat strings like YYYYMMdd and compare them as numbers

Comment: Is it generally best practice to keep the dates as date object and only format when displayed on the UI ?

Comment: I think yes, because date object keeps more information, like time, miliseconds, timezone

Comment: @Sergej—date instances only store one value: a time value that is milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch (1970-01-01). Everything else (offset, hours, minutes, etc.) is calculated on each *get* call.

Answer (score 0):

I think dates are best compared in their object format to in other for you to get the actual date value.

I have tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of variants, if want to compare, should format strings near to ISO format (yyyy MM dd) which is comparable, for example to sort array of your strings:

```
// let array = [...your format strings];
let sortedArray = array
    .map(str => {
        let [dd, MM, yyyy] = str.split('.');
        return `${yyyy}.${MM}.${dd}`;
    })
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .map(str => {
        let [yyyy, MM, dd] = str.split('.');
        return `${dd}.${MM}.${yyyy}`;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your dates are stored as String. You may try the following way,

1) First Set Dateformat in SQL
it will set the one format.

2) cast/convert the values and put them in variables.

3) Then you can compare or find the dates in between (between)

Hope this helps.